# Remove groups when specific date not contained in date column in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataframe as follows:

```
  city district      date  price
0   bj       cy  2019/3/1    NaN
1   bj       cy  2019/4/1    6.0
2   sh       hp  2019/2/1    4.0
3   sh       hp  2019/3/1    4.0
4   bj       hd  2019/3/1    7.0
5   bj       hd  2019/4/1    NaN
```

How could I remove groups of `city` and `date`, if they didn't have entry of `2019/4/1`.

At this case, groups of `sh` and `hp` should be removed, since it only has data for `2019/2/1` and `2019/3/1`.

My desired output will like this:

```
  city district      date  price
0   bj       cy  2019/3/1    NaN
1   bj       cy  2019/4/1    6.0
2   bj       hd  2019/3/1    7.0
3   bj       hd  2019/4/1    NaN
```

Sincere thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution with [`DataFrameGroupBy.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

f = lambda x: x['date'].eq('2019-04-01').any()
df = df.groupby(['city','district']).filter(f)
print (df)
  city district       date  price
0   bj       cy 2019-03-01    NaN
1   bj       cy 2019-04-01    6.0
4   bj       hd 2019-03-01    7.0
5   bj       hd 2019-04-01    NaN
```

Faster solution with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html):

```
df = (df[df.assign(t = df['date'].eq('2019-04-01'))
           .groupby(['city','district'])['t'].transform('any')])
print (df)
  city district       date  price
0   bj       cy 2019-03-01    NaN
1   bj       cy 2019-04-01    6.0
4   bj       hd 2019-03-01    7.0
5   bj       hd 2019-04-01    NaN
```

Comment: Your second solution works fast and correctly, thanks for help me today.